# PrimeNg Schedule styles do not work

Tags: angular, primeng

I am having trouble trouble getting the styles for the schedule in primeng to work. [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdtXz.jpg)

Comment: What kind of trouble do you run into? Can you post code and error messages please?

Comment: I do not get any error messages. You can see the trouble I'm having with the picture I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install

```
npm install fullcalendar
npm install jquery
npm install moment
```

and then include the dependencies in angular-cli.json as

under styles add

```
"../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css"
```

and under script add

```
 ../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
 "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"
```

This should do the trick

**update**

If you are not using angular-cli please use

```
<link href="node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the index.html and

```
'moment': 'npm:moment',
'jquery':'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.js',
 'fullcalendar':'npm:fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'
```

in system.config.js

Comment: Is there a work around angular-cli.json? I am working on an existing app that does not have angular cli.

Comment: do you have Systemjs.config.js in the project directory ?